# Как получать событие на удаленный сервер о push в Gitlab SaaS?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, git, gitlab

Идея такая, при каждом push получать событие(которое можно использовать), а так же желательно список commit'ов в push'e на сервер ubuntu

Как это можно реализовать на python отошлите пожалуйста чтива где искать, уже 2 дня ломаю голову над решением этого шага

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html

Comment: Насколько я понял, это работает только если у вас Gitlab стоит на выделенной тачке, а у меня SaaS
Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Именно так оно и есть.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html